# Sql Equivalent to UInt16

Tags: c#, sqldatasource, sqldatatypes

I know that the Sql equivalent of Int16 is SqlInt16.

But what is the Sql equivalent of UInt16, UInt32 and Uint64?

Answer (score 3):

Except for tinyint, there are no native unsigned types in SQL server so there is no good equivalent.  The best you can do is use a bigger precision number and add a constraint on the permissible values.

Comment: MySQL has the UNSIGNED attribute, if you can use it.

Comment: But what would be the case of UInt64? What would be thye bigger precision?

Comment: @JMSA, I'm not familiar enough with SQL's data types to provide a good answer to that.  Hopefully someone else will chime in with a bigger type that can suite this need.

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, for Unit 64: decimal(20,0) with a check constraint between 0 and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.